# Why is Sinatra web server giving a 500 error from this POST method?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, forms, http-post

I'm building a Ruby web app with Sinatra, and am using a form to pass parameters to a POST page, which should have rendered dynamic content based on those parameters.

However, when it came time to test the POST method and submitting the form, the following was displayed in the browser:

> Internal Server Error
>
> bad content body

When this happens, the error log shows:

> Error: EOFError: bad content body

followed by a stacktrace of files I'm not working with and then:

```
"POST /list/AUser'sName" HTTP/1.1 500 294
```

Code for the form:

Note - This page is just used for redirecting to a different page, determining the correct form action= attribute.

```
<form action="/list/<%=name%>" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type='Submit'/>
</form>
```

POST method in the server.rb file:

```
post '/list/:name' do
    "Hello World"
end
```

Comment: This is also my first question here, so any tips on making my question better are also welcome.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in your form being posted.

Comment: Try using an input field with a value and name, additional to your submit button. Then there will be something to send to the server

Comment: I probably should have mentioned, this is on an intermediary page that is just used to re-direct to the correct page, and am using embedded ruby to determine what that should be. 
I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the enctype= attribute, the form is now working as intended.

From what I've learned, the enctype attribute is only used when uploading a file that needs to be submitted with the form. I had it included here because of past issues on different forms where logic errors occurred when it was not included.

Thanks to all for the comments and suggestions.